# ArcGIS Runtime SDK for Android throwing error while handling userToken in user credentials

Tags: java, android, gis, arcgis, arcgis-server

I am new to this ArcGIS Map. I am developing an application where we are using a user token instead of passing username and password in User Credentials.

UserCredentials creds = new UserCredentials();
creds.setUserToken(map_token, referral);

I am stuck at this point. What do I really have to pass in as a parameter for referral? I tried passing null and empty string as a parameter but I get an error message saying "token or referral cannot be empty string"

When I passed some parameter I am getting "com.esri.core.io.EsriServiceException not found" exception

What do I really need to pass in place of refferal? Why am I getting these errors?

Can someone help me with this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you made sure to initialize the client in your Application class (i.e. ArcGISRuntime.setClientId("CLIENT_ID"); )?